# nlog moving log halfway through program execution

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a program that does the following things

1. Start program execution, log timestamp
2. Read command line inputs and parses arguments
3. Based on arguments, creates a new log in the desired directory
4. Continues logging in desired directory

My issue is that the logs generated from step 1 are stored in a different file than those generated in step 4. Is there an easy way to move the log location during step 3 instead of creating a new log? Or is there any easy way to copy the contents of the first log into the second log? Or am I going about this all wrong and there's a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Could you update your question to include your `NLog.config` that defines the 2 file-targets (and logging-rules), and also include the source-code that creates the different NLog-Logger-objects and how events are logged ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving the execution timestamp to a variable and logging it once you have decided where you want your logs to be.